# Error while trying to use nativescript-photoviewer with vue

Tags: vue.js, nativescript

I'm developing an app with nativescript-vue and I need to show some external images.

I'm trying to use nativescript-photoviewer plugin.

This is my code:

```
<template>
...
<Image :src="image_path" @tap="onImageTap" />
...
</template>

<script>
// Include the module
import { PhotoViewer, PhotoViewerOptions, PaletteType, NYTPhotoItem } from "nativescript-photoviewer";
...
methods: {
 onImageTap: function() {
            let image1 =
                "https://pat-book.es/storage/user_images/allergies/3qwTKMNU2tRqHhJtFRce5S3fNgel9twafrFl9FWj.jpeg";
            let image2 =
                "https://pat-book.es/storage/user_images/allergies/4MtvyhpyzHIdj993pEj3MoubmRJQWAhGdhotaT6h.jpeg";

            let images = [image1, image2];

            let photoViewer = new PhotoViewer();

            photoViewer.showGallery(images);
}
</script>
```

The images are intended to be dynamic.

I'm not using options provided that they are optional.

This is the error that I'm getting:

```
JS: [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'startIndex' of undefined"
System.err: An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.
System.err: Calling js method onTouch failed
System.err: TypeError: Cannot read property 'startIndex' of undefined
System.err:
System.err: StackTrace:
System.err: PhotoViewer.showGallery(file:///app\photoviewer.android.ts:21:41)
System.err:     at onImageTap(file:///app\pages\allergies\AllergiesDetailsPage.vue:173:0)
...
```

This is the plugin's source code where the error is rising:

```
    public showGallery(imagesArray: Array<string>, options?: PhotoViewerOptions) {
        var photosArray = new java.util.ArrayList();
    
        imagesArray.forEach((imgUrl: string) => {
            photosArray.add(imgUrl);
        });
    
        let startIndex: number = options.startIndex || 0; // Line 21
...
```

Has anyone managed to run this plugin with vue? The only examples provided are for angular and typescript.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing empty object as second argument to *showGallery* method, looks like its not really an optional parameter.

```
photoViewer.showGallery(images, {});
```